# Select query inside the foreach loop in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How to implement the select query inside the foreach loop I am selecting the ids from array and passing inside the select query

```
$query_user= "SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key='devstate' AND meta_value='$user_state'";
$query_value= $wpdb->get_row($query_user, OBJECT);
$user_id_value= $query_value->user_id;
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query_user) or die(mysql_error());


foreach( $result as $results ) {
    $id=$results->user_id;
    echo $id;
    $my_query="SELECT * FROM $table where ID='$id'";
    $val123= $wpdb->get_row($my_query, OBJECT);
         $email123= $val123->user_email;
         echo $email123;
         echo $val123->user_email;

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working yet? There should be absolutely no problem to nest queries

Comment: What error or problem are you seeing currently? It's not clear what you want us to help with, specifically

Comment: when i am echo the variable user_email or $val123 it is not giving value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried passing the variable like this:

```
$my_query="SELECT * FROM $table where ID=". $id;
```

Or tried to dump the select variable like this:

```
echo($my_query);
```